# Supports médiatiques ou supports communicatifs ou... ?

Tags: vocabulaire, professions

Imaginez que vous travailliez à la réalisation à la fois d'un livre, d'un documentaire vidéo, d'un site web et d'articles pour divers médias. (La même idée est déclinée en diverses formes. Ces formes pourront être diffusées d'une façon ou d'une autre sur l'un ou l'autre média.)

Comment résumeriez-vous votre activité ?

> Je travaille à la réalisation de différents supports communicatifs.

(Cette expression ne semble pas très courante sur le web. Et on ne la retrouve d'ailleurs pas dans le [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=support%20communicatif&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) )

ou

> Je travaille à la construction de différents médias (ça sonne bizarre)

ou

> Je travaille à la construction de différents supports médiatiques (il me semble que ça sonne plus « communiqué de presse » que travail de fond)

Je ne peux pas dire que je travaille « dans différents médias » puisque cela pourrait sous-entendre par exemple que je suis *employé* à la fois par une chaîne TV et un journal, alors que je travaille en indépendant. (Sans compter que je construis ces « supports », je ne les diffuse pas, pour l'instant.)

Et vous, comment diriez-vous ?

Comment: Ne pouvez vous pas utiliser une tournure différente ? Dans l'idée "Je travaille dans la communication, sur différents supports médiatiques". Personnellement, je préfère "travailler sur des supports" que "construire des supports"

Comment: Il me semble que l'on emploie plus souvent "supports de communication" que "supports communicatifs".

Comment: @Random je ne travaille pas "dans la communication" (c'est un  métier en soit qui n'a rien à voir avec ce que je fais). Je te remercie pour la suggestion qui suit.

Comment: @BinaryOverride merci pour ta suggestion !

Comment: Est-ce un même contenu qui est décliné en diverses formes ou bien les contenus sont différents selon les supports?

Comment: @mouviciel c'est le premier : globalement  la même idée est déclinée en diverses formes. Ces formes pourront être diffusées d'une façon ou d'une autre sur l'un ou l'autre média. (Merci, j'ai édité ma question !)

Answer (score 6):

Avant de répondre directement à votre question, je souhaite rectifier certaines expressions et élucider certains points si vous permettez:

**1.** L'expression:

> Support communicatif

a un sens particulier et tout à fait différent de celui que vous souhaiteriez exprimer. Je vous donne l'exemple d'un [routeur](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routeur): c'est un support communicatif dans le sens où il communique les données (dits paquets, en langage informatique) qu'il reçoit.

Autrement dit, un support communicatif sous-entend que c'est le support lui-même qui agit, qui fait la communication: et dans un ce sens, il n'est plus un simple support mais un agent (au sens acteur) de communication.

Pour cela, il faut plutôt écrire:

> Support de communication

**2.** Pour ce qui est des éléments que vous venez de citer:

- *un livre*: c'est un support écrit
- *un documentaire vidéo*: c'est un support audio et vidéo
- *un site web*: c'est un support numérique
- *articles pour divers médias*: un article peut être un support écrit (au format papier) ou numérique (fichier word, fichier PDF, etc.)

**3.** Revenons à votre question proprement dite:

> Et vous, comment diriez-vous ?

En effet, la personne chargée de la production de chacun des éléments que vous venez de citer porte un nom précis: par exemple, pour ce qui est du site web, vous pouvez être qualifié au sein d'un entreprise comme *Chargé de projet web*. Vous pouvez être également qualifié de *concepteur rédacteur* dans le secteur de la publicité, etc.

Néanmoins, vu la description que vous venez de donner à travers votre question et vos commentaires, et si vous travaillez ici en France alors sachez que votre métier est déjà désigné, par exemple, par le [Répertoire national des certifications professionnelles (RNCP)](http://www.rncp.cncp.gouv.fr/) par l'expression: ***[Concepteur de supports de communication](http://www.rncp.cncp.gouv.fr/grand-public/visualisationFiche?format=fr&fiche=11507)*** . Il faut y lire la description `5)` pour que vous puissiez en rendre compte.

Mais comme vous exercez en régime indépendant, vous pouvez écrire simplement:

> Je suis **concepteur indépendant de supports de communication**

Si toutefois vous ne travaillez pas ici en France, vous pouvez exprimer la même idée autrement:

> Mon travail consiste à concevoir et à produire des
>   supports de communication.

Comment: Pour éviter l’ambiguïté à l'oral, je préférerais: **Concepteur indépendant de supports de communication**

Comment: @jlliagre oui, je vous donne raison et je viens de l'éditer conformément à votre  proposition , merci